# Unable to scroll to bottom cell of UITableViewController embeded in Container View

Tags: ios, swift, uicontainerview

I have a UITableViewController embedded in a Container View. The prototype cell bounds are larger than the bounds of the container view it appears in. When trying to view the lower half of the bottom-most table cell, I can drag and pull up and see the content, but on release, it immediately bounces back to having the top of that cell aligned with the top of the container view. Note this only happens for the bottom-most cell.

Is there a particular storyboard setting that will allow me to scroll all the way to the bottom of the cell, or does this have to do with constraints of the prototype cell/container view?

Here are the storyboard settings on my container view:

[Container View Settings 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nv0ws.png)
[Container View Settings 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIhUO.png)

Here are the ones for the TableView:
[Table View Settings 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhKrr.png)
[Table View Settings 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmGc8.png)

TableViewController Settings:
[Table View Controller Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQRih.png)

As for the code:

I have my custom table view cell:

```
class MakerItemTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var itemImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var itemTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var itemDescription: UILabel!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Here is where I instantiate and add the child view in the MainViewController:

```
private lazy var itemsViewController: MakerItemsTableViewController = {
        // Load Storyboard
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)

        // Instantiate View Controller
        var viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MakerItemsTableViewController") as! MakerItemsTableViewController

        // Add View Controller as Child View Controller
        self.add(asChildViewController: viewController)

        return viewController
    }()


private func add(asChildViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
        // Add Child View Controller
        addChildViewController(viewController)

        // Add Child View as Subview
        childView.addSubview(viewController.view)

        // Configure Child View
        viewController.view.frame = view.bounds
        viewController.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

        // Notify Child View Controller
        viewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }
```

I started learning Swift a few weeks back and a lot of what I have is answers adapted from other stack overflow questions and spliced into my project, so I apologize in advance for any poor conventions!

In the screenshot below, the top of the image is the top of the table cell. The bottom of the bar across the top meets up with the upper bound of the container view. If I click down on the image and pull up, I can see the information below it that is part of the same cell, and at the same time the image disappears under the bar across the top. This acts as I would expect. The information lower in the cell fills the container view area. However, as soon as I let go of the click, the image pulls itself back down and once again the top of the image (which is the top of the table cell) is aligned with the top of the container view.

[Simulator Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bW1RV.png)

UPDATE: The issue seems to be with the constraints of the UIView that is acting as the container view. I haven't found a full solution yet but have narrowed it down to this being the issue.

Comment: Can you share some code? Or are you able to recreate this with a sample project?

Comment: Added the screenshots of setting on the storyboard objects, and some code. Please let me know if there is anything else I can add that would help!

Comment: I am still not sure of what problem you are facing. A screenshot/gif of the offending TableVC would be nice.

Comment: I added a more thorough description of what is happening

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the code that you have mentioned here.

That problem that you are facing is because the tableView height is not able to be determined. Please try adjusting it  (increase or decrease) or check its top-bottom-leading-trailing constraints.

hope it would help you solve the issue. :)

Comment: Nimish, it seems that the tableview only has the option to set a row height, and this is currently set to automatic

Comment: @SeanGeier. I agree. But please can you once set the row height manually heightForRow at IndexPath method ?. And Also check tableView constraints to its superView?.

Comment: Nimish, you were correct that the issue lies with the constraints. I am experimenting with the constraints of the UIView that is the container view now. By setting it to a very large value, I am able to scroll down and see the full cell, but I do not think this is the proper fix for the issue now, I need to have the UIView height automatically adapt to the height of the table view cell

Comment: @SeanGeier. You can always experiment buddy. but these two are the main points to keep in mind when solving this type of problem.

Automatic dimension in not working properly in your case otherwise this would not have happened. You should check the views, buttons inside the cell and check if their height can be easily estimated or not. 

"Automatic dimension cannot work in every case."

Answer (score 0):

I had to do a few things to get this to work. There was a tab bar that was being carried over from the source controller, and so the table view controller embedded in the container view in the destination controller did not see it. I had to uncheck "Extend Edges Under Bottom Bars" and also under the Simulated Metrics tab, change "Bottom Bar" to "Translucent Tab Bar" so that the table view would have a placeholder to not extend under.